# Health check in .Net 7.0 worker service

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, worker, health-check

I'm building a worker service in .Net 7.0 and I would like to add a health check on port 80.
The problem is that I should run this worker in a docker mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0
and I cannot use  to use

`IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
...

```
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); 

    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => 
    { 
        options.ListenAnyIP(80); 
    }); 

    services.AddRouting(); 
}) 
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => 
{ 
    webBuilder.Configure(app => 
    { 
        app.UseRouting(); 

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => 
        { 
            endpoints.MapGet("/keepalive", async context => 
            { 
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Alive"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    }); 
})
.Build();`
```

Because at runtime in the docker I get :

You must install or update .NET to run this application.
App: /app/PhotowebOrderMonitoringService.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

How can I simply add a health check in my .Net 7.0 worker without using ConfigureWebHostDefaults ?

Many thanks.

I tried a lot of different techniques without success and always fallback in the use of ConfigureWebHostDefaults...

Comment: Ensure your Docker base image is `dotnet/aspnet` and not `dotnet/runtime`.